# Export blob from mysql to file in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that, among other things, extracts information from a mysql database. I tried the following to extract a file from entry 20:
`mysql -se "select file_column_name from table where id=20;" >file.txt`

That gave me a file.txt with the file name, not the file contents. How would I get the actual blob into file.txt?

Comment: And where is the actual blob stored?

Answer (score 1):

Turn the value in `file.txt` into a variable and then use it as you need to? i.e.

```
blobFile=$(cat file.txt)
echo "----- contents of $blobFile ---------"
cat $blobFile
# copy the file somewhere else
scp $blobFile user@Remote /path/to/remote/loc/for/blobFile
# look for info in blobfile
grep specialInfo $blobFile
# etc ...
```

Is that what you want/need to do?

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that'll do me much good since I don't have admin on the mysql server and have no clue where the blob file is stored after upload. (Data is entered through a web page.) I thought that the blob was actually stored in the database and I could get it that way the same way I grab a number from an int field and use it as a loop condition.
+1 and thanks for the idea. It'll solve my problem once I figure out how to implement it.

Comment: So your blob filename isn't something you can immediately use, like /path/to/dir/with/mySong.mp3? It may help others to offer better solutions by editing your question to include the contents of your file.txt AND to indicate how you want to use it. Good luck.

Comment: That's right, it's not something I can use right away. I doubt posting what I want to do with it will help because I've already tested that portion of my script on sample data and it works fine.